# Load custom JS file dependent on backend module settings

Tags: magento

I want to add a custom JS file to my module only if an attribute ("yes/no") in the module backend settings is set to "yes".

So far I have referenced my layout.xml file in the module config.xml like this:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <modulename>
                <file>modulename.xml</file>
            </modulename>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

The layout.xml loads the .js file as expected. Though I would like to add a dependency similar to the ones in the system.xml file if that is possible:

```
<sortby translate="label">
    <label>Sort by:</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>40</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <source_model>path/to_settings</source_model>
    <depends><sortby>1</sortby></depends>
</sortby>
```

Anyway, how can I load a custom JS file dependent on the value of a backend settings field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as follows :

```
<reference name="head">
    <block ifconfig="path_to_setting" type="your_block_type" name="some_name">
        <action method="addJs"><script>path_of_file.js</script></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Replace the things with your values

**ifconfig** attribute value is true it will load your JS file.